# Google Compute Networking Describe Forwarding Rule Error

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have created a forwarding rule via HTTP load balancing in Google Cloud Platform.  When trying to describe it, I get an error.  **How can I describe the forwarding rule on the command line?**  I'm sure that's the correct region and I've tried selecting all the region choices.

`gcloud compute forwarding-rules list`

```
NAME                REGION IP_ADDRESS     IP_PROTOCOL TARGET
my-forwarding        X.X.X.X  TCP         my-target-proxy
```

`gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe my-forwarding`

`For the following forwarding rules:
 - [gondolin-forwarding]
choose a region:
 [1] asia-east1
 [2] europe-west1
 [3] us-central1
 [4] us-east1
Please enter your numeric choice:  3`

`ERROR: (gcloud.compute.forwarding-rules.describe) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/my-project/regions/us-central1/forwardingRules/my-forwarding' was not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know forwarding rules may be defined both as regional (i.e. existing in a given region) as well as global resources. It looks like your resource dos not exist in the region us-central1. Could you please try to find it in the global namespace:

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe my-forwarding --global
```